# A relationship about normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given two random variables, $X\sim N(\mu_{1},\sigma_{1})$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_{2}, \sigma_{2})$ where $\mu_{1},\mu_{2}>0$.

> If $\sigma_{1}<\sigma_{2}$ and $a>1$, Can we conclude the following relationship? $$P(X>E[X]a)<P(Y>E[Y]a).$$

Comment: If $\mu_1<0, \mu_2>0$ then let $a\to \infty$.

Comment: Let $\mu_1 = 1, \mu_2=10^{100}, \sigma_1 = 1, \sigma_2=2$ and set $a=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write instead $$P((X-\mu_1)/\sigma_1 > \mu_1(a - 1)/\sigma_1) = 1 - \Phi(\mu_1(a-1)/\sigma_1)$$ and similarly for $Y$, where $\Phi$ is the normal cdf. Hence the statement is equivalent to
$$
\Phi(\mu_1(a-1)/\sigma_1) > \Phi(\mu_2(a-1)/\sigma_2),
$$
which due to monotonicity is equivalent to 
$$
\frac{\mu_1(a-1)}{\sigma_1} > \frac{\mu_2(a-1)}{\sigma_2}.
$$
To this end, since $a > 1$,
$$
\frac{(a-1)(\mu_1\sigma_2 - \mu_2\sigma_1)}{\sigma_1\sigma_2} > 0 \iff \mu_1\sigma_2 > \mu_2\sigma_1.
$$
Notice that $\sigma_1 < \sigma_2$ is not needed.